# JSR303 Composite Annotation

Tags: java, bean-validation

I've created a composite annotation that consists of @Digits and @Min

```
@Digits(integer=12, fraction=0)
@Min(value=0)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target( { FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
public @interface PositiveInt {
     String message() default "{positive.int.msg}";
     Class<?>[] groups() default {};
     Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

my problem is, I want to reuse this annotation where I want the @Digits 'integer' value to be specify when the PositiveInteger is use

example

```
public Demo{
    @PositiveInteger(integer=1)
    private Integer num1;

    @PositiveInteger(integer=2)
    private Integer num2;
}
```

where num1 can be 1-9, and num2 can be 1-99.

Is this even possible, if so, how do I go about this?

Currently, I have to provides a custom ConstraintValidator where i would have my validation code for the @Digits and @Min

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target( { FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, PARAMETER })
@Constraint(validatedBy=PositiveIntConstraintValidator.class)
public @interface PositiveInt {
         String message() default "positive.int.msg";
     Class<?>[] groups() default {};
     Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

     int integer() default 1;
}


public class PositiveIntConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<PositiveInt, Number> {
    private int maxDigits;

    @Override
    public void initialize(PositiveInt constraintAnnotation) {
    maxDigits = constraintAnnotation.integer();

    if (maxDigits < 1){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid max size.  Max size must be a positive integer greater than 1");
    }
}


@Override
public boolean isValid(Number value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    if (value == null){
        return true;
    }
    else if (value instanceof Long || value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Short || value instanceof BigInteger){
        String regex = "\\d{"0," + maxDigits + "}";
        return Pattern.matches(regex, value.toString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i think this is a way to go, but are you sure you need regexp validation after type check? you can just check size of the String

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what you are actually asking and it seems your code/example is not consistent either. Could you maybe rephrase your question?

Answer (score 20):

You could make use of [@OverridesAnnotation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition):

```
@Digits(integer=0, fraction=0)
@Min(value=0)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target( { FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
public @interface PositiveInteger {
    String message() default "{positive.int.msg}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint=Digits.class, name="integer")
    int digits();
}
```

That way the value given in `@PositiveInteger#digits()` will be propagated to `@Digits`.

Comment: thanks.  i think this is what i've been looking for.  I will try this out.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The OP should accept this answer.