# Java Constraint Annotations: Passing Parameter Value To Composite Constraint

Tags: java, validation, annotations

I'm trying to create my own composite validation annotation to validate a String - so far it is made up of the annotations @NotNull, @NotBlank and @Size

However, I do not want to leave these at default values and want to be able to pass in a parameter value, for example if I do @ValidString (min = 1, max = 50), then the @Size annotation can read these values - is this possible?

My constraint -

```
@NotNull()
@NotBlank()
@Size()
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidStringValidator.class)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidString {
    String message();
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    int min() default 1;
    int max() default 255;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSR303 Composite Annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844161/jsr303-composite-annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but your annotation can contain other annotations, e.g.

```
@NotNull()
@NotBlank()
@Constraint(validatedBy = ValidStringValidator.class)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidString {
    String message();
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    Size size() default @Size(/*enter default size arguments here*/);
```

}

Answer (score 5):

You may use [OverridesAttribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/OverridesAttribute.html)

```
@Size(min=1, max=255)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, FIELD })
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
public @interface ValidString {
    String message();
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint=Size.class, name="min")
    int min() default 1;

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint=Size.class, name="max")      
    int max() default 255;
}
```