# Java Annotation Composition, re-using attributes

Tags: java, annotations, composition

I would like to do something like this:

```
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.fetchSize", value = FetchSize.value()))
@Target({ })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface FetchSize {
    String value();
}
```

The part that doesn't work is **value = FetchSize.value()**. I would like to hand the value attribute from @FetchSize to the target annotation @QueryHint so that I can annotate like this:

```
@FetchSize("1000")
```

Is something like that possible somehow, and how would I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, such a thing is not possible. Values for annotation attributes must be constant expression (and/or a few other types, like `enum` types).

What you're trying to do here is dynamically reference the value of another annotation attribute. That's not possible.

If you control the annotation processor, then you can do that logic there. If you don't you're pretty much out of luck and will have to rethink your design.

Comment: I found this answer browsing around a bit more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13844161/jsr303-composite-annotation

Sadly, it doesn't work for my case because I would have to override the value of the inner annotation in the nested QueryHints / QueryHint cascade. At least that's how I read it.